# Why is this selector's projector function returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx

I am trying to create a selector that returns part of a feature selector. 
State is populated ansynchroniously via effect but starts with empty array.

Problem is that the projector function gets undefined passed in and I don't see why anymore.

**selector.ts**

```
import { createFeatureSelector, createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';

import { ChartState } from '../reducers/chart.reducer';

export const selectChartState = createFeatureSelector<ChartState>('chart');

export const selectFrameworksState = createSelector(
  selectChartState,
  (chart: ChartState) => chart.frameworks // <= here chart is undefined??
);
```

**reducer.ts**

```
import { Framework } from 'src/app/_interfaces/framework.interface';

import { Action, createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';

import * as ChartActions from '../actions/chart.actions';

export interface ChartState {
  frameworks: Framework[];
}

export const initialState: ChartState = {
  frameworks: []
};

export const chartReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,

  on(ChartActions.loadCharts, state => state),
  on(ChartActions.loadChartsSuccess, (state, action) => {
    return {...state, frameworks: [...action.data]};
  }),
  on(ChartActions.loadChartsFailure, (state) => state),

);

export function reducer(state: ChartState | undefined, action: Action) {
  return chartReducer(state, action);
}
```

**module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...  
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    StoreModule.forFeature('chart', reducer),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([ChartEffects]) // forFeature() not working? Action provider?
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ]
})
export class ChartModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
foo$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectFrameworksState));
```

Comment: My first guess would be that you are trying to access the `chart` slice before its defined. Is the component instantiated after importing the `ChartModule` into your app?

Comment: I thought so too but should the selector then not return the initial state of an empty array? it is the app.component and the ChartModule is lazy loaded. But then again I would think that the selector (part of ChartModule would not be available but it is)

Comment: @Jota.Toledo you are right. I moved the call to the selector to the lazy loaded chartModule and it works. So that means that I cannot select parts of a feature from other modules? I guess I also probably should not to decouple the modules.

Comment: The feature selector returns null, as the slice is not defined in the state. The initial value for it is set when its `reducer` function is loaded into your app, which happens after loading the `ChartsModule`.If you correctly handle `chart` being undefined in your `selectFrameworksState` and return null, you could then do something like `this.store.pipe(select(selectFrameworksState),filter(val=>!!val))`. I guess that after loading the `ChartsModule` the stream above should emit the initial value. But having to handle a null slice sounds like an antipattern to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector is called before the lazy loaded feature slice of the state is initialized.

Access from within the ChartModule (where feature state is defined) the selector works fine.

It is also recommended to decouple the state and only use it from within its module. If state is needed accross the whole app it might be better to move it to the root state.

Thanks to @Jota.Toledo

Answer (score 1):

Although for a different reason - I just came across this issue for me and finally found out why. So I figure I'd share for others who might end up here for that same reason.

My issue was that I had mistyped the `featureName` in one instance.

The `createFeatureSelector` `featureName` parameter in the selectors needs to match the `StoreModule.forFeature` `featureName` parameter in the module or you will also get this undefined issue.